# Relationship between reciprocal and subtraction minimization problems

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization

Suppose that I have $M$ 2-dimensional vectors $x^{(1)}, \dots, x^{(M)}$. I know that for all $i$, $x^{(i)}_2\geq x^{(i)}_1>0$. I would like to solve the following minimization problem:

$\ell^* = \text{argmin}_{1\leq i\leq M}\big[x^{(i)}_2-x^{(i)}_1\big]$

My question is, if $\ell^*$ is the solution to the above minimization problem, is it also the solution to the one below?

$\ell^* = \text{argmin}_{1\leq i\leq M}\frac{x^{(i)}_2}{x^{(i)}_1}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, take the vectors $(1,3)$ and $(10,20)$. The first one has the smallest difference but the second one has the smallest ratio.